# Graphing tools for Windows phone- Visiblox Error

Tags: windows-phone-7, charts, visiblox

I have been trying to use 3rd party tool called visiblox for rendering charts in my app.
http://www.visiblox.com/examples

The Visiblox docs says, we need to add the toolkit dll and visiblox dll. I have localised the datepicker. For that I have added the toolkit source project to the solution.

And I have unblocked and added the visiblox reference as they have mentioned. But I get an error which says

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
>      at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
>      at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
>      at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)

I see build succeed, but when i click the xaml file, the designer does not get loaded and it gives the error. .

Now i remove the project toolkit reference, and add the toolkit dll that came along with the visiblox download. And the designer works perfectly!! But no localisation of the date picker.

http://www.visiblox.com/blog/2011/02/visiblox-for-wp7-basic-charts-selection-and-zooming

Any suggestions? :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of the WP7 toolkit did you localize?  Visiblox Charts or WP7 2.2 includes the Nov 2011 release of the toolkit so if you're using a different version that could well be the problem?

Comment: i localised the Feb 2011 toolkit :O

Comment: I have downloaded the august toolkit and it has a LocalizedResources Folder with the datetime picker localisation. Even when i change the language, the date time  picker shows done and cancel in english! :(

Comment: I have localised and added nov 2011 toolkit and everything works! Thank  you :)